# JS keyboard keydown event to unicode

Tags: javascript, html, events

I'm trying to capture user input (for custom non-html input field) so I need unicode hex key of input character

Others answers suggest something like this:

```
function detectkey(event) {
    var unicode = event.which || event.keyCode;
    document.getElementById("keystroke").innerHTML = "The pressed key was: " + String.fromCharCode(unicode) +"<br>The Unicode value is:"+ unicode;
}
```

But both `event.which` and `event.keyCode` and also charCode are deprecated
Proofs:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode

As you can see here https://keycode.info/
There are 2 ways left - event.key and event.code

- But event.key gives you 'shift', 'control' and other stuff
- And event.code is a joke

Answer (score 0):

Damn seems like I need to use `keypress` event instead. It don't gives you control presses

UPD: Damn*2, it's also deprecated

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event